# OpenGL 4.6 batch rendering draws nothing

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glad

I tried to rework the code from [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures) to handle batch rendering.
But only a dark background is displayed. Highlights of my program:

```
#include "batch_2D.hpp"
#include "shader_loader.hpp"
#include <algorithm>

Batch2D::Batch2D(int const &m_count) {
    count = m_count;
    program = getMinimalProgram("texture_vertex.glsl", "texture_fragment.glsl");

    GLuint const indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3, // first triangle
        1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };


    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);


    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (sizeof(float) * 32) * count, NULL,
        GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);

    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // position attribute
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (8 * sizeof(float)), (void*)0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // color attribute
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (8 * sizeof(float)), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // texture coord attribute
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (8 * sizeof(float)), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);



}


void Batch2D::push(vec2 const vec[4]) {

    if (batches.size()==0)
    {
        batch_data b;
        init_batch(b);
        batches.push_back(b);
    }

    if (sizeof(batches[batches.size() - 1].verticies)==sizeof(float)*32*count)
    {
        flush();
    }


         float vertices[] = {
            // positions               // colors           // texture coords
             vec[0].x,vec[0].y, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   vec[0].x + 0.5f,vec[0].y + 0.5f, // top right
             vec[1].x,vec[1].y, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   vec[1].x + 0.5f,vec[1].y + 0.5f,// bottom right
             vec[2].x,vec[2].y, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   vec[2].x + 0.5f,vec[2].y + 0.5f, // bottom left
             vec[3].x,vec[3].y, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   vec[3].x + 0.5f,vec[3].y + 0.5f  // top left 
        };
        
        

        int size1 = *(batches[batches.size() - 1].verticies + 1) - *batches[batches.size() - 1].verticies;

        

        int size2 = (sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]));

            float* result = new float[size1 + size2];
            std::copy(batches[batches.size() - 1].verticies, batches[batches.size() - 1].verticies + size1, result);
            std::copy(vertices, vertices + size2, result + size1);


            batches[batches.size() - 1].verticies = result;

            batches[batches.size() - 1].count = batches[batches.size() - 1].count + 6;
        
}

void Batch2D::push(GLuint const &texture) {

    for (batch_data& b : batches) {
        if (b.texture==texture)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (b.texture==0)
        {
            b.texture = texture;
        }
    }
    
    batch_data b;
    init_batch(b);
    b.texture = texture;
    batches.push_back(b);

}


void Batch2D::push(GLuint const &texture, vec2 const vec[4]) {
    push(texture);
    push(vec);
}

void Batch2D::draw(batch_data const &batch) {

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, batch.texture);

    glUseProgram(program);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(batch.verticies),
        &batch.verticies[0]);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    //glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, 0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, batch.count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, batch.count);
}


void Batch2D::flush() {
    for (batch_data &b : batches) {
        draw(b);
        //free(b.verticies);
        //glDeleteTextures(1, &b.texture);

    }
    batches.clear();
}

void Batch2D::init_batch(batch_data &batch) {
    batch.count = 0;
    //batch.verticies = new float[count*32];
    batch.verticies =(float *) malloc(count*32*sizeof(float));
}


Batch2D::~Batch2D() {
    flush();
    glDeleteProgram(program);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
}
```

```
#include "batch_game.hpp"
#include "textures.hpp"


BatchGame::BatchGame() :BaseGame() {
    batch = new Batch2D(10);
    texture = texture2D("picture.jpg", 100, 100);


    vec[0].x = 0.5f;
    vec[0].y = 0.5f;


    vec[1].x = 0.5f;
    vec[1].y = -0.5f;


    vec[2].x = -0.5f;
    vec[2].y = -0.5f;


    vec[3].x = -0.5f;
    vec[3].y = 0.5f;
}




void BatchGame::act() {




}

void BatchGame::draw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    batch->push(texture, vec);
    batch->flush();

}



BatchGame::~BatchGame() {
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
}
```

Header file:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef BATCH_2D_HPP
#define BATCH_2D_HPP

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <vector>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

using namespace glm;



typedef struct {
    //std::vector<float> verticies;
    GLsizei count;
    GLuint texture;
    float* verticies;
    int verticies_count;
    GLuint* elements;
    int elements_count;
}batch_data;




class Batch2D
{
public:
    Batch2D(int const &m_count);
    ~Batch2D();
    void push(vec2 const vec[4]);
    void push(GLuint const &texture);
    void push(GLuint const &texture, vec2 const vec[4]);
    void flush();
private:

    void prepare_verticies(batch_data& batch, vec2 const vec[4]);
    void prepare_elements(batch_data& batch);

    void init_batch(batch_data &batch);
    void draw(batch_data const &batch);
    
    std::vector<batch_data> batches;


    int count;
    GLuint program;
    GLuint VAO;
    GLuint VBO;
    GLuint EBO;


};

#endif // !BATCH_2D_HPP
```

My shaders:

```
#version 460 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

```
#version 460 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

// texture sampler
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

The rest of the program works fine, OpenGL only gives me 2 warnings (same as with the original code):

```
GL CALLBACK:  type = 0x8251, severity = 0x826b, message = Buffer detailed info: Buffer object 2 (bound to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, usage hint is GL_STATIC_DRAW) will use VIDEO memory as the source for buffer object operations.
GL CALLBACK:  type = 0x8251, severity = 0x826b, message = Buffer detailed info: Buffer object 1 (bound to GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (0), GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (1), GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_ARB (2), and GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, usage hint is GL_DYNAMIC_COPY) will use VIDEO memory as the source for buffer object operations.
```

The original program works fine, so I am sure I created the context, texture, and shaders correctly. I think I broke something with the RAM, or with the VBO.

Comment: Does your code call `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress);` before the loop, and `glfwSwapBuffers(window)`, and `glfwWaitEvents()` or `glfwPollEvents()`, inside the loop?

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find the Batch Renderer in the link you provided, so I had to make some assumptions about the Code.

I suppose that verticies is a float* to an array since it makes the most sense. In that case, I don't understand what size1 is supposed to do. You are taking the second element of the array, and subtracting the first element from it. This will always gives you sizeof(float). And if I'm correct with the assumption that verticies is a float* to an array, then the first std::copy call in Batch2D::push(vec2 const vec[4]) will copy only the first 2 elements of the verticies array, and the second std::copy call will copy the entire vertices array, but it will copy it into the result array, starting at the second element. So you are essentially overwriting the result array with the vertices array.

Also it would help if you provided headers for the Batch2D class so that we can know more info and don't have to make assumptions.